# Orchard: Remove items from menu inside dashboard

Tags: asp.net-mvc, orchardcms, orchard-modules

I learning Orchard and I don't success to remove item from menu (inside dashboard not site),
I use this guide for create new module  [Writing a Content Part](http://docs.orchardproject.net/en/latest/Documentation/Writing-a-content-part/).

My migration looks:

`public int Create(){ 
           // Creating table MapRecord
            SchemaBuilder.CreateTable("MapRecord", table => table
                .ContentPartRecord()
                .Column("Latitude", DbType.Double)
                .Column("Longitude", DbType.Double)
            );
            ContentDefinitionManager.AlterPartDefinition(
                typeof(MapPart).Name, cfg => cfg.Attachable());
            ContentDefinitionManager.AlterTypeDefinition("Map", builder =>
            builder
                .WithPart("CommonPart")
                .WithPart("TitlePart")
                .WithPart("MapPart")
                .Creatable()
                .Draftable());
            return 1;
        }`

[image: I have new item in menu]

My new module works fine but now I want to remove the "Map" from the menu
how I do it?

**Edit for new user that read this post**

Ok, I succeeded that related to content Types we can remove from site or from the code

That remove all "Map" type (like devqon said in comment)

```
public int UpdateFrom3()
        {
            ContentDefinitionManager.DeleteTypeDefinition("Map");

            return 4;
        }
```

better options we can unflag the `Creatable()`

```
    public int UpdateFrom3()
       {

             ContentDefinitionManager.AlterTypeDefinition("Map", builder =>
              builder
                  .WithPart("CommonPart")
                  .WithPart("TitlePart")
                  .WithPart("MapPart")
                  .Creatable(false)
                  .Draftable());

             return 4;
       }
```

Comment: I hope you didn't actually apply your `.DeleteTypeDefinition("Map")`? This removes your `Map` type as a whole, not only from the menu

Comment: Yes I saw that :) I only practice,
now I trying to unflag `Creatable()` from the code

Comment: If you already flagged it as `Creatable()`, you can do a new `UpdateFromN` with `.Creatable(false)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is caused by the creatable flag. Just remove it to get rid of the menu item, either in the migration by removing `Creatable()` or go to content types and untick the checkbox.